# $G$-torsor over $\mathbb{A}^1_S$ where characteristic of $S$ does not divide $|G|$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

I am reading the paper [*$\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory of schemes* by Morel and Voevodsky](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1999__90__45_0) from 1999. There is a proposition saying that

> Let $G$ be a finite étale group scheme over $S$ of order prime to the characteristic of $S$. Then the object $B_\text{ét}G$ in the model category of simplicial étale sheaves is $\mathbb{A}_1$-local. Here $B_\text{ét}G$ is the étale sheafification of $BG$ constructed by applying bar construction sectionwise.

I am confused about the proof. First, we can assume that $S$ is $\operatorname{Spec} R$ where $R$ is a strict henselian local ring. Then to prove that $B_\text{ét}G$ is $\mathbb{A}_1$-local, we need to show that $BG(\mathbb{A}^1_S)$ is weakly equivalence to $*$. Since $\pi_0(BG(\mathbb{A}^1_S))$ is the set of $G$-torsors over $\mathbb{A}^1_S$, we need to show that such torsors are trivial.

Then they said that *it is because of the homotopy invariance of the completion of $\pi_1^{ét}$ outside of characteristic*, and referred to SGA4 without classifying which part they referred to. I wonder whether there is an explanation?

Comment: What does "characteristic of $G$" mean?

Comment: You don't have to show that BG(A¹) is weakly equivalent to the point, but that it's weakly equivalent to BG(S) (that is, the nerve of the groupoid with one object and $G$ automorphisms, since S is strictly henselian).

Comment: @DenisNardin Sure. But in order to show that $BG(\mathbb{A}^1)$ is w.e. to $BG(S)$, we need to show that $\pi_0(BG(\mathbb{A}^1))$ is trivial since so is $BG(S)$ (in étale topology).

Comment: @DenisNardin Sorry, there is a typo in my original post. I said we needed to show that $\pi_1(BG(\mathbb{A}^1))$ is trivial, but I should say we need to show that $\pi_0(BG(\mathbb{A}^1))$ is trivial.

Comment: A $G$-torsor over $\mathbb{A}^1$ would be an étale $G$-covering of $\mathbb{A}^1$. The homotopy invariance of the étale fundamental group implies that completion away from the characteristic of the fundamental group of $\mathbb{A}^1_S$ (over strictly henselian $S$) is trivial. Therefore, $G$-torsors must be trivial if the order of $G$ is prime to the characteristic.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt Can you give a reference about the homotopy invariance of the étale fundamental group?